# How to show that a free ultrafilter cannot have an infinite pseudointersection?

Tags: set-theory, filters, infinitary-combinatorics

The following text is a quote from [p.180](http://books.google.com/books?id=NZVb54INnywC&pg=PA180) of Halbeisen's book *Combinatorial Set Theory*.
This book is also available  [on website](http://www.math.uzh.ch/index.php?ve_vo_det&key2=1501) of a course taught by the author. (As mentioned in Asaf's comment, it is also available on the [author's website](http://user.math.uzh.ch/halbeisen/publications/publications.html).)

> For two sets $x,y\subseteq\omega$ we say that $x$ is almost contained in $y$, denoted $x\subseteq^*y$, if $x\setminus y$ finite.
>
> A *pseudo-intersection* of a family $\mathscr F \subseteq [\omega]^\omega$  of infinite subsets of $\omega$ is an infinite subset of $\omega$ that is almost contained in every member of $\mathscr F$.
>
> Furthermore, a family $\mathscr F \subseteq [\omega]^\omega$  has the *strong finite intersection property* (sfip) if every finite subfamily has infinite intersection.
>
> For example any filter $\mathscr F \subseteq [\omega]^\omega$  has the sfip, but no ultrafilter on $[\omega]^\omega$ has a pseudo-intersection.

- How can we show that a free ultrafilter cannot have an infinite pseudointersection?

This fact is used to show that $\mathfrak p$ is well-defined and $\mathfrak p \le \mathfrak c$,
where 
the *pseudo-intersection number* $\mathfrak p$ is the smallest cardinality
of any family $\mathscr F \subseteq [\omega]^\omega$ which has the sfip but which does not have a pseudo-intersection.

I will post my proof below; but I wonder whether there are different ways to show this.

Comment: The book is also available on the author's website.

Comment: You mean [here](http://user.math.uzh.ch/halbeisen/publications/publications.html), right?

Comment: Yes, exactly there.

Comment: Martin, in that last paragraph, $\frak p\leq c$ regardless to anything, because every family in $[\omega]^\omega$ has cardinality $\leq\frak c$.

Comment: Of course, you are right. I have changed the wording to *$\mathfrak p$ is well-defined and $\mathfrak p \le \mathfrak c$* which is the same wording as in the book. (Maybe I should have left there only the first part.)

Answer (score 6):

Let $\mathscr F$ be an arbitrary ultrafilter, which contains no finite sets.

Suppose that $A$ is an infinite pseudointersection of $\mathscr F$.

Then we have $A\subseteq^* G$ for each $G\in\mathscr F$.

Since $\mathscr F$ is an ultrafilter, we have either $A\in\mathscr F$ or $\omega\setminus A\in\mathscr F$. But $\omega\setminus A$ cannot be in $\mathscr F$, since $A\setminus (\omega\setminus A)=A$ is infinite and thus $A\not\subseteq^* \omega\setminus A$.

So we get that $A\in\mathscr F$.

Now denote $A=\{a_n; n\in\omega\}$ and let $B=\{a_{2n}; n\in\omega\}$ and $C=\{a_{2n+1}; n\in\omega\}$. Since $A=B\cup C$ and $\mathscr F$ is an ultrafiter; one of the sets $B$, $C$ belongs to $\mathscr F$.
But neither $A\subseteq^* B$ nor $A\subseteq^* C$ holds, which yields a contradiction.

Comment: This looks right, but there are seemingly a bunch of unnecessary moves (see my answer below).

Answer (score 5):

Let $\mathcal U$ be an ultrafilter on $\omega$, and let $x$ be a pseudo-intersection of $\mathcal U$. Furthermore, let $y$ be such that both it and its compliment contain infinitely many elements of $x$ (for instance, $y$ could be your $B$). Then, either $y$ or $\omega\backslash y$ are in $\mathcal U$, so either $x\backslash y$ or $x\backslash (\omega\backslash y) = x\cap y$ is finite, which is impossible.